# Regex to match html comments, in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex in javascript, that replaces all occurences of `<!-- foo -->` in a string.

I tried:

```
thestring.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*-->/gm, "")
```

but that doesn't work, and even breaks my text.

I can't use `.*` as that excludes newlines.

Sample multiline comment:

```
<!-- foo
    bar
          baz-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
thestring.replace(/<!--[^]*-->/gm, "")
```

or use lazy `?` to make the previous quantifier find the shortest match:

```
thestring.replace(/<!--[^]*?-->/gm, "")
                           ^
<!-- a comment here -->  oops, ignore? -->
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As a side note, if you're trying to parse html using regexp, I suggest you take a look at the top answer here:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `/<!--[\w\s]+-->/g`

```
const re = /<!--[\w\s]+-->/g
const str = 'test <!-- foo --> abc'
console.log(str.replace(re, ''))
```

Edit: OP's code seems fine?

Comment: Apologies, I was a bit hasty there.